# JSON - Character issue

Tags: json, r, rmongodb

I extracted some data from a mongo database using the RMongo library. I have been working with the data with no problem. However, I need to access a field that was saved, originally in the database, as JSON. Since rmongodb saves the data as data frame, I now have a large character vector of length 1:

```
res1 = "[ { \"text\" : \"@Kayture Beyoncé jam session ?\" , \"name\" : \"beponcé \xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbc\xbb\" , \"screenName\" : \"ColaaaaTweedy\" , \"follower\" : false , \"mentions\" : [ \"Kayture\"] , \"userTwitterId\" : \"108061963\"} , { \"text\" : \"@Kayture fucking marry me\" , \"name\" : \"George McQueen\" , \"screenName\" : \"GeorgeMcQueen12\" , \"follower\" : false , \"mentions\" : [ \"Kayture\"] , \"userTwitterId\" : \"67896750\"}]"
```

I need to extract all the "text" attributes of the objects from this array (there are 2 in this example), but I can not figure out a fast way. I was trying using strsplit, or going from character to json files using jsonlite, and then to list, but it does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: You say that `rmongodb` supplies the data as `data.frame` so that now you have a character vector - I don't get it... Maybe you provide some code how you communicate with MongoDB through `rmongodb`.

Comment: Sure, sorry about this... I edited my original question, as I am using RMongo instead. I extract the collection using col <- dbGetQuery(mongo, "collection", "{}", 0, n), where n is the number of objects I extract. col is a data frame.

Comment: so what is `res1` then?

Comment: res1 is an element of a column of "col". I am working with twitter data. So, each tweet has a "replies" field, which may have 1 or several replies, which is what res1 shows. When I use dbGetQuery, the "replies" column gets stores as a character array of length 1 (per tweet), but in reality is a JSON object (or a list in R). Sorry for not being clear in my question, and thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting from

```
res1 = "[ { \"text\" : \"@Kayture Beyoncé jam session ?\" , \"name\" : \"beponcé \xed\xa0\xbc\xed\xbc\xbb\" , \"screenName\" : \"ColaaaaTweedy\" , \"follower\" : false , \"mentions\" : [ \"Kayture\"] , \"userTwitterId\" : \"108061963\"} , { \"text\" : \"@Kayture fucking marry me\" , \"name\" : \"George McQueen\" , \"screenName\" : \"GeorgeMcQueen12\" , \"follower\" : false , \"mentions\" : [ \"Kayture\"] , \"userTwitterId\" : \"67896750\"}]"
```

you can use `fromJSON()` from the `jsonlite` package to parse that JSON object.

```
library(jsonlite)

fromJSON(res1)

                            text           name      screenName follower mentions userTwitterId
1 @Kayture Beyoncé jam session ? beponcé í ¼í¼»   ColaaaaTweedy    FALSE  Kayture     108061963
2 @Kayture fucking marry me      George McQueen GeorgeMcQueen12    FALSE  Kayture      67896750
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to convert to JSON and then use fromJSON, my mistake. Thanks again!